# Can I sign into two Steam accounts on the same PC?

Tags: steam

I have two Steam accounts with a variety of games. One was when I was younger that I lost access to and recently got back and the other is one I've used until now. Potentially, is there anyway to download Steam to one hard drive and log into one account there and then download Steam again to a different hard drive and sign into my other account on that one? I just really hate signing out and signing back in every time I want to play something else.

Comment: @DavidYell Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: It wasn't, it was just a comment as I didn't research it or check if it was correct :)

Comment: It's pity Steam doesn't support account merge, that would be the best in such cases as yours. But your problem is [not new](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/3zn6sh/how_to_fast_switch_steam_accounts_you_were_logged/).

Comment: @Sinatr They take a firm stance on their policy to not merge accounts nor to ever transfer games because the amount of people that would get tricked into losing games is too damn high. Also, it doesn't support their core business model aptly named "profit".

Answer (score 22):

You can't have Steam installed multiple times on the same machine. However, what you can do is enable [Family Sharing](https://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing) between the 2 accounts so you always got access to most games on both accounts.

> How do I enable Family Library Sharing on my computer?
> To enable
> Family Library Sharing, first be sure you have Steam Guard security
> enabled via Steam > Settings > Account in the Steam Client. Then
> enable the sharing feature via Settings > Family, (or in Big Picture
> mode, Settings > Family Library Sharing,) where you'll also authorize
> specific computers and users to share.

This won't give access to all games, because the publisher can decide to disable family sharing.